# how to implement sql like casting selection in lambda expressions

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008, lambda

how to convert this sql statement into linq or lambda expression

> SELECT Month,Year FROM Tbl_OrderDetails Order by cast(Year as int) ,cast(Month as int)

Here Month and Year are in `VARCHAR` type

Thanks all,

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var skata = from ordtls in Tbl_OrderDetails 
             orderby (int)ordtls.Month, (int)ordtls.Year 
             select new {ordtls.Month,ordtls.Year}
```

or

```
 var skata = from ordtls in Tbl_OrderDetails 
             orderby Convert.ToInt32(ordtls.Month), Convert.ToInt32(ordtls.Year) 
             select new {ordtls.Month,ordtls.Year}
```